# como hacer click en un check box que active una y que desctive la otra casilla de un listview expandible

Tags: android

Quiero hacer que al momento de darle click en un elemento checkbox del listview me active y si hay alguna otra que lo desactive.

```
@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, final boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final int mChildPosition = childPosition;
    final String item = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.config_child, null);
    final CheckBox checkConfig = convertView.findViewById(R.id.rButton);
    checkConfig.setText(item);
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Saludos, podrías por favor colocar un poco mas de código de lo que estas haciendo, y también colocar que has intentado? solo con ese fragmento no se sabe como esta estructurada tu vista, ni la forma en como intentas implementar el Checkbox.